# SQLITE PIVOT TABLE WITH COUNT

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, pivot

Can you help me plase ?
I want a result like the table below with Sqlite

| . | task_name | status_code | department |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | START | PUR |
| 2 | B | START | ENG |
| 3 | C | FINISH | ENG |
| 4 | D | NOT ACTIVE | DES |
| 5 | E | START | DES |
| 6 | F | NOT ACTIVE | ENG |

| . | START | FINISH | NOT ACTIVE | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PUR | 1 |  |  | 1 |
| ENG | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| DES | 1 |  | 1 | 2 |

Comment: Please include your sample table as plain text that can be copied and pasted (Preferably a `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for easy importing into a database, but CSV works too).

Answer (score 5):

You can use conditional aggregation such as

```
SELECT department,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status_code = 'START' THEN 1 END) AS "START",
       SUM(CASE WHEN status_code = 'FINISH' THEN 1 END) AS "FINISH",
       SUM(CASE WHEN status_code = 'NOT ACTIVE' THEN 1 END) AS "NOT ACTIVE",
       COUNT(*) AS total
  FROM t
 GROUP BY department
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=937912fbcbf9775f766def17a964f542)</kbd>